# Create a parameter in rdlc report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, report, rdlc

I am a newbie to rdlc reports.
I need to create a parameter that i will pass to a subreport. However I cannot find where in the report designer to create parameters.I am using VS 2010

Thanks in advance

Comment: More details on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302459/how-to-pass-textbox-combobox-value-to-rdlc-report-text-field/10427228#10427228

Comment: More details on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302459/how-to-pass-textbox-combobox-value-to-rdlc-report-text-field/10427228#10427228

Answer (score 53):

Have you tried View --> Report Data? Then you should see Parameters in the Report Data window. 
This is how I get to the parameters in VS2010.

Comment: Remark: in VS2012 the Report Data item is located at the end of View menu, if it is not there (re)open the RDLC file.

Comment: In VS2013 (cannot verify in earlier), shorcut `Ctrl+Alt+D`. It's the last option in View Menu.

Comment: Shortcut works in 2008 as well, but it's missing in the view menu (Shortcut seems to be the only way to get it).

Comment: adding to @tomash ... the _Report Data_ item is at the BOTTOM of the menu ... the very very bottom where  you don't always look

Comment: I assume the RDLC UI was done by the 'B' team. I find it easier just to edit the .rdlc file in a text editor for a lot of things. =/

Comment: In VS2015 the shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+D as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick remark for people using VS2008: open the RDLC in the designer and a Report main menu item should appear. The first sub-menu item is Report Parameters. You can configure the parameters from there.