# How to pass textbox/Combobox value to rdlc report text field?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reporting

c#, mysql in my project.

In that i create a rdlc report. I dont know to pass winform textbox value to rdlc report text field.

I googled and try some set of code. but cant get that.

If you worked in report. please help me.

**My requirement is,..**

I am doing college project. In that they asked bonafide certificate. So i create a winform With reportviwer, name, course, year, semester, academic year, purpose textboxs and one button. Click the button when the textboxes are filled. those text values want to pass the record textboxes.

Is it possible any way.

**my report...**

[image]

Comment: I do that in single box with passing total value in use of String Concatenation method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to setup a parameter for each of the fields you want to bring in and set the value of the parameter to whatever you want in your C# app. In the report you would then set the value of each text box to be the parameter and it should work just fine.

Or if you are using RDLC files (which you are) you could put your data into a dataset and pass that to the report and then have each field in the report a column in the dataset

Answer (score 13):

Set the parameters using LocalReport property in the Report Viewer

C# Code :

```
ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ParameterName", "Value"));
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

Comment: for everyone searching for ReportParameterCollection namespace, its
`using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;`

Comment: Is there an other way without STRING name parameter ? I mean Using autocompletion ? If I change the name of the parameter, build will not raise error...

Answer (score 1):

1) Create parameter in RDLC Report. 
2) Place the parameter Where you want in the RDLC Input Textbox property. 
3) Type the below code in Reprot.cs page. 
4) Passing the parameter value where you redirect the Report page.

```
ReportParameter[] parms = new ReportParameter[n];
parms[0] = new ReportParameter("param_name", textbox(n-1).text);
parms[1] = new ReportParameter("param_course", textbox(n).text);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

**following method worked for me i used vb.net2010**

1: In Visual Studio 2010, open your .rdlc file, and open “Report Data” window (If you can not see this window, go to View menu to open it);

2: Right click the “Parameters” node, and add a new Parameter, ie: named it “startdate“;

3: In your .rdlc file, add a textbox, named it tbContent, and set its filed express to :

=Parameters!startdate.Value

4: Go to your Form file which include your reporterview control, and add the following code:

```
  Dim rptparameter As ReportParameter
  rptparameter = New ReportParameter("content", txt_startdate.Text)
  rv_param.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {rptparameter})
  rv_param.LocalReport.Refresh()
```