# Passing parameters to rdlc file in mvc at runtime

Tags: model-view-controller, parameters, report, rdlc

I created quite a few rdlc reports in visual studio. I have them exporting to excel, pdf, image, and word. Now I need to set parameters so at runtime, the user can define a start date and end date for a certain field. That field is PSURcvd. I have added parameters StartDate and EndDate to the rdlc "HolbrookReceived". But I do not know how to assign them to the PSURcvd field and how to prompt text boxes at runtime for the date inputs. How do i do this?

Here is the code in my controller.

```
 public ActionResult HolbrookReceivedReport(string id)
    {
        LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "HolbrookReceived.rdlc");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            lr.ReportPath = path;
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        List<TblPSU> cm = new List<TblPSU>();
        using (PSU_DatabaseSQLEntities dc = new PSU_DatabaseSQLEntities())
        {
            cm = dc.TblPSUs.ToList();
        }
        ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("HolbrookReceivedDataSet", cm);
        lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
        string reportType = id;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;



        string deviceInfo =

        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        renderedBytes = lr.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);


    }
```

Here is my view

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Ramona Holbrook Received <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("HolbrookReceivedReport", new { id = "PDF" })">PDF</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("HolbrookReceivedReport", new { id = "Excel" })">Excel</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("HolbrookReceivedReport", new { id = "Word" })">Word</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("HolbrookReceivedReport", new { id = "Image" })">Image</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Did this help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following and see if that helps you out.
[How to pass textbox/Combobox value to rdlc report text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302459/how-to-pass-textbox-combobox-value-to-rdlc-report-text-field/10427228#10427228)
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=859BmmVOm8M