# How to bind multiple table to RDLC report

Tags: c#, .net, report, rdlc

I have stored procedure that returns multiple table as a dataset. 
The amount of the table is always dynamic depends on selected parameters before.
I wanna bind that dataset into rdlc report, is it possible to bind using rdlc report? how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use report parameters instead of binding data. In my experience, it is always easier to work with report parameter collection rather than binding tables to rdlc when working with dynamic datasets.

Comment: I would be appreciate if you share link or example, how to pass parameter collection and how to read the parameter collection at the report. Thanks

Comment: This is an example for passing a textbox value. You can change this to pass your values. It works like aHashmap. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2vcrqtIUyw

Comment: This will help you too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302459/how-to-pass-textbox-combobox-value-to-rdlc-report-text-field

Comment: ]https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/755c4bde-031d-431c-829d-000fe36f5a0b/how-to-programmatically-pass-parameters-to-a-reportviewer-i-c-net?forum=vsreportcontrols

Answer (score 0):

public partial class LoanSummaryReport : Form
{

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public LoanSummaryReport(DataTable dtSummaryAccount, DataTable dtLoanSummaryDetail, DataTable dtLoanActivity, DataTable dtDetailTransaction)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ds.Tables.Add(dtSummaryAccount);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtLoanSummaryDetail);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtLoanActivity);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtDetailTransaction);
        ds.AcceptChanges();

        
    }

    private void LoanSummaryReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource("LoanSummaryDS", ds.Tables[0]);
        ReportDataSource rds2 = new ReportDataSource("LoanSummaryDetailDS", ds.Tables[1]);
        ReportDataSource rds3 = new ReportDataSource("LoanActivityDS", ds.Tables[2]);
        ReportDataSource rds4 = new ReportDataSource("DetailTransactionDS", ds.Tables[3]);

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds2);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds3);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds4);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).