# Compile time Error for Passing value from a TextBox to RDLC report

Tags: c#

I want to pass a textbox value to RDLC report. For said purpose my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System.IO;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;

ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", t1.Text));
this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
```

But i get the error during compile time which is:

```
Error   15  The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Report.SetParameters(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter>)' has some invalid arguments   

Error   16  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameterCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter>'
```

This error occurs on following line:

```
this.reportViewer2.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

Help is required to resolve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: i have upate question to show full error message

Comment: Looks like you're mixing WebForms and Winforms. Choose one, and stick with it. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302459/how-to-pass-textbox-combobox-value-to-rdlc-report-text-field#comment38655295_10427228

Comment: i have upate question to show  using statements

Comment: @rene got solution by replacing  WebForms with Winforms

Comment: Get rid of  `using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;` and instead use `using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;`

Comment: @ rene thanks for help. Post the answer so that i accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error by replacing `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms` with `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms`