# Print Parameter in Report

Tags: vb.net, report, reportviewer

This is my VB.NET (2012) code to show report based on `Combobox` *(cmbCustomer)* selection, I want to print that parameter `cmbCustomer.text` on report.

```
Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
        Me.rpt_customerByDateTableAdapter.Fill(Me.customerByDateDataSet.rpt_customerByDate,
        cmbCustomer.Text)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how, assuming you have already created a parameter in your [`rldc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512117/create-a-parameter-in-rdlc-report)

```
Dim customer As String = cmbCustomer.text
Dim CustomerParam As New ReportParameter("yourCustomerParameter", customer)

Dim reportParameters() As ReportParameter = {CustomerParam}

Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.customerByDateDataSet.rpt_customerByDate,
        cmbCustomer.Text)

Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters)
Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I think Me.rpt_customerByDateTableAdapter.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters) must be Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters)